# Cliff hanging scene in Mission Impossible: Fallout

Tags: reference, mission-impossible, mission-impossible-fallout

Towards the end of *Mission Impossible: Fallout*, we see Ethan hunt yet again hanging from a cliff to fight off August Walker.

Was it just a typical "Impossible" action sequence or was it a deliberate callback of the erstwhile cliff hanging scene from the intro of MI : 2.

Comment: You should really add a spoiler tag to this. Especially since you are describing the final confrontation of a film that came out less than a week ago.

Comment: @foxsfer No. Please note that the title doesn't spoil anything. And once you click on a question asking specifically about *Mission Impossible: Fallout*, you obviously know what you're getting yourself into. For more information, check the corresponding section in the [help center](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I personally feel like it was a deliberate callback, but I have no sources to back that opinion up. I also felt some very strong *The Princess Bride* vibes while watching that scene, and really hope the similarities were intentional.